# Some Kotlin Libraries attached to this project were compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Android studio is up to date

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This error shows as soon as I connected app with firebase. I checked for the latest kotlin stable version , it says you already have latest version. Then I checked for latest android studio update, it says up-to-date. Btw I am using android studio bumblebee. When I tried to download Flamingo , virus detected.

I am attaching gradle files

**Build Gradle : Project level**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build gradle : module level**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.chatterbox"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely not using the latest Kotlin:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
```

`1.6.21` has been released more than a year ago. Please try `1.8.22`.

Comment: I did this but still same error is showing.

Comment: See if you can run the Gradle `build` task. Gradle tasks should be somewhere in the right sidebar in the Android Studio.